# Getting error in Spark SQL when trying to concat '}' character

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case where I need to concat a '}' to a string using Spark SQL. The sample dataset is as below:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----+
|col_1                                 |col_2|
+--------------------------------------+-----+
|{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2"}|abcd |
+--------------------------------------+-----+

root
 |-- col_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col_2: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to check the length of `col_1` and based on that add value of `col_2` into the JSON-formatted string of `col_1`. I have written a Spark SQL query as below:

```
select *, case when length(col_1) = 2 then
concat(substring(col_1, 0, length(col_1) - 1), '"col_2":"',cast(col_2 as STRING), '"}')
else concat(substring(col_1, 0, length(col_1) - 1), ',"col_2":"', cast(col_2 as STRING), '"}')
end as mod_col_1
from df
```

The query parsing fails when encountering the '}' character. Is there any way to add/escape this character in the query. Or any way to generate the desired string.
Expected output:
when col_1 = "{}"

```
+--------------------------------------+-----+
    |col_1                                 |col_2|
    +--------------------------------------+-----+
    |{}|abcd |
    +--------------------------------------+-----+
```

output:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|col_1|col_2|mod_col_1                                 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|{}|abcd             |{'col_2' : 'abcd'}|
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

when,
col_1 = {"key_1" : "val_1", "key_2" : "val_2"}

```
+--------------------------------------+-----+
        |col_1                                 |col_2|
        +--------------------------------------+-----+
        |{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2"}|abcd |
        +--------------------------------------+-----+
```

output:

```
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|col_1|col_2|mod_col_1                                 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2"}|abcd             |{"key_1" : "val_1"key_2" : "val_2","col_2":"abcd"}|
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Happy to share more details if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the regexp_replace() function.
Check this

```
spark.sql(s"""
with t1 ( select '{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2"}' col_1, 'abcd' col_2 
         union all
         select '{}', 'defg' )
        select *, case
          when col_1 = '{}' then "{ 'col_2' : '"||col_2|| "'}"  
          else regexp_replace(col_1,"[}]",":")||"'col_2' : '"|| col_2 || "'}"
           end x from t1
""").show(50,false)
```

Output:

```
+-------------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
|col_1                                |col_2|x                                                     |
+-------------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
|{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2"}|abcd |{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2":'col_2' : 'abcd'}|
|{}                                   |defg |{ 'col_2' : 'defg'}                                   |
+-------------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Update:
To get the output in double quotes, wrap it in single quotes

```
spark.sql(s"""
with t1 ( select '{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2"}' col_1, 'abcd' col_2 
         union all
         select '{}', 'defg' )
        select *, case
          when col_1 = '{}' then '{ "col_2" : "' ||col_2|| '"}'  
          else regexp_replace(col_1,"[}]",":")||'"col_2" : "'|| col_2 || '"}'
           end x from t1
""").show(50,false) 

+-------------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
|col_1                                |col_2|x                                                     |
+-------------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
|{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2"}|abcd |{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2":"col_2" : "abcd"}|
|{}                                   |defg |{ "col_2" : "defg"}                                   |
+-------------------------------------+-----+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I have tried your solution but can the new values be enclosed in double quotes. Below is the desired output for the new column.

{"key_1" : "val_1","key_2" : "val_2","col_2" : "abcd"}
{ "col_2" : "defg"}

Comment: @RajnilGuha updated the answer.. SQL's default is wrapping in single qoutes for strings, so you should be good.

Comment: Thanks you so much for taking the time to help.

Comment: you are welcome.. hope you get the merits of triple quotes, it helps to solve double & single quote issues in problems like this.